# How to remove "#" in svelte spa router?

Tags: web, url-routing, svelte, uri-fragment

I use svelte-spa-router npm module for the router of my svelte project.
When using this module it adds "#" in the URL in default to denote it is the spa router.
Such as "localhost:5000/#/app/.." I want to remove this "#" and make the router as the whole router such as "localhost:5000/app" Could anybody help me with this, please?

Comment: Have a look at the docs for an uri hash or fragment to understand why it's used in an SPA to route from fragment to fragment is an single page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment and https://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/deep-dive-into-client-side-routing-navigo-pushstate-hash

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible with `svelte-spa-router`. This package is a hash-based router, and the "#" is key to how this type of router works. From the [package docs](https://github.com/ItalyPaleAle/svelte-spa-router#hash-based-routing):

> With hash-based routing, navigation is possible thanks to storing the current view in the part of the URL after `#`, called "hash" or "fragment".
>
> For example, if your SPA is in a static file called `index.html`, your URLs for navigating within the app look something like `index.html#/profile`, `index.html#/book/42`, etc. (The `index.html` part can usually be omitted for the index file, so you can just create URLs that look like `http://example.com/#/profile`).
>
> When I created this component, other routers for Svelte 3 implemented navigation using the HTML5 history API. While those URLs look nicer (e.g. you can actually navigate to `http://example.com/profile`), they are not ideal for static Single Page Applications. In order for users to be able to share links or even just refresh the page, you are required to have a server on the backend processing the request, and building fully-static apps is much harder as a consequence.
>
> Hash-based routing is simpler, works well even without a server, and it's generally better suited for static SPAs, especially when SEO isn't a concern, as is the case when the app requires authentication. Many popular apps use hash-based routing, including GMail!

If you want your URL to not have a "#", you will need to switch to a HTML5 history-based router such as [svelte-routing](https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-routing) or [routify](https://github.com/roxiness/routify).